# cURL error 6: Could not resolve host, after successfully resolving host

Tags: php, guzzle, shopware6

I need to update all media in a larger Shopware shop, with about 10000 products. I use the [Shopware php SDK](https://github.com/vienthuong/shopware-php-sdk) by [vienthuong](https://github.com/vienthuong). I download 200 product objects at a time, create an upsert with their cover media id within a while loop.

It all goes well and good for about 2000 products. Then, nothing happens for a while, and then I get a  "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host after resolving host before":

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: foo-shop.de (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://glogner-shop.de/api/oauth/token in /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(158): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(110): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#3 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RetryMiddleware.php(67): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#4 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RetryMiddleware.php(114): GuzzleHttp\RetryMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#5 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RetryMiddleware.php(106): GuzzleHttp\RetryMiddleware->doRetry(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#6 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/RejectedPromise.php(42): GuzzleHttp\RetryMiddleware->GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException))
#7 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\RejectedPromise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#8 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(248): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true)
#9 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(224): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#10 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(269): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#11 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(226): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#12 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#13 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#14 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/vin-sw/shopware-sdk/src/Client/Client.php(108): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('POST', 'https://glogner...', Array)
#15 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/vin-sw/shopware-sdk/src/Client/Client.php(135): Vin\ShopwareSdk\Client\Client->request('POST', 'https://glogner...', Array)
#16 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/vin-sw/shopware-sdk/src/Client/AdminAuthenticator.php(56): Vin\ShopwareSdk\Client\Client->post('https://glogner...', Array)
#17 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/token.php(15): Vin\ShopwareSdk\Client\AdminAuthenticator->fetchAccessToken()
#18 /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/main.php(61): require('/Users/miamahnc...')
#19 {main}
  thrown in /Users/m/Desktop/updater-dev/coverImage/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 210
```

So, the error is telling me that it can't get the auth token, which worked fine before.

Code:

```
$time_pre = microtime(true);
require __DIR__ . '/token.php';

$criteria = new Criteria(1, 200);
$criteria->setTotalCountMode(1);

$criteria->addInclude('product', ["coverId"]);
$page_count = 1;
$total_product_count = 0;
do{
  $context = new Context($config['shop_url'], $accessToken);
  $syncService = new SyncService($context);

  $data = [];
  $payload = new SyncPayload(); 

  $productRepository = RepositoryFactory::create(ProductDefinition::ENTITY_NAME); 
  $products = $productRepository->search($criteria, $context); //EntitySearchResult
  $criteria->setPage($page_count);

  if(microtime(true) >= $time_pre+(10*50) ){
    echo "getting new token! \n";
    $time_pre = microtime(true);
    require __DIR__ . '/token.php';
    $context = new Context($config['shop_url'], $accessToken);
    $syncService = new SyncService($context);
  }



  $total_product_count += $products->count();

  foreach( $products->getEntities()->getElements() as  $key => $entity){
    $ci = $entity->coverId;
    if(!is_null($ci)){ 
      $data[] = array('id' => $ci, 'position' => 0);
    }

  }

  $payload->set(ProductMediaDefinition::ENTITY_NAME . '-upsert', new SyncOperator(ProductMediaDefinition::ENTITY_NAME, SyncOperator::UPSERT_OPERATOR,
        $data
    ));


  if(microtime(true) >= $time_pre+(10*50) ){
    echo "getting new token! \n";
    $time_pre = microtime(true);
    require __DIR__ . '/token.php';
    $context = new Context($config['shop_url'], $accessToken);
    $syncService = new SyncService($context);
  }
  
$response = $syncService->sync($payload);

  ++$page_count;

}while($products->getMeta()->getTotal() - $total_product_count > 0);
```

It's not that pretty anymore, but I just want it to work first.

Comment: You probably have networking problems.

Comment: What do you mean by networking problems? As far as I understand it: I don't think so. I can reproduce it , and I it always works the first few rounds. I do update some media products. Other requests are processed correctly as well.

Comment: It really sounds like some problem with your network setup, not with Shopware. Is this a remote server? Did you try to make the calls from the same machine to the same machine? Could there be some firewall or other protection system in place? What I am thinking is, that after making lots of requests, something is blocking it. But the exception you are getting seems DNS error, wondering how this could be blocked. To rule this out you can also put the host name and IP statically to /etc/hosts. What happens if you ping the Shopware server for a while? Are there any problems?

Comment: Please also share your `token.php` (anonymized) - it might be a problem with the token renewal. Which might kick in after the 500 seconds (which might be just correspondent to the 2000 products)? After which time did you get the exception? Can you stop watch the timing?